# How to cache images in nginx, but allow to override cache?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to add "expires" headers to my files on nginx, BUT allow us to override them by adding a query string to the end. This is the config I have:

```
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        expires     max;
    }
```

I have a script that allows people to rotate and image, and then it reloads the image to show the newly rotated image. The problem I'm having is that it doesn't always work!

We add `"?dummy="+$.now()` to the end of the image name, so that normally would force the browser to download the image again.

This logic works fine on our Apache server, but I can't quite get it working right on nginx (it seems to only work half of the time)

Am I missing something?

FWIW: I don't really want to have to rename the image, as this means we would also have to rename all the thumbnailed versions as well - for which there are quite a few.

Here is the information from the image first:

[image]

And this stays the same when you rotate the image (even though I can see a new network request, and requesting it with a new **dummy=xxx** param)

If I force a reload of the page, this is what I see:

[image]

So the "Last Modified", "E-Tag" etc stuff IS being updated, but for some reason the browser isn't recognising it :/

Comment: I don't think I understand what is it that you say that stays the same.  The question makes no sense.  What is it that the browser isn't recognising?

Comment: @cnst - The IMAGE isn't being updated. As I said: So the "Last Modified", "E-Tag" etc stuff IS being updated, but for some reason the browser isn't recognising it :/

Comment: That doesn't really sound possible.  And sounds like it may be a browser issue, or, even more likely, issue with your code outside of nginx, or code in nginx you haven't shown us.  Besides, the screenshots of the headers you've provided show no signs of any `expires` directives taking place, so, the question is beyond vague ATM, as it shows completely unrelated screenshots and nginx snippets.

Comment: @cnst - I have already sorted this, by the awkward way of renaming the file every time they rotate the image. As I said, if you look at the `Last-Modified`, you can see the time has changed from 8:36:18 to 8:36:21, so its recognising the image has changed, BUT its not showing it (even with **?dummy=xxx** added to the end of the filename)

Comment: What you say makes little sense -- the content-length is different, clearly the images served are different, so, nginx should hardly be the one to blame.

Comment: I know it makes no sense - that's why I was asking the question! It did it across browsers, so I don't think it was browser specific. I could see the network  request for the image (with dummy appended to it), and yet it still got the old version. Anyway, as I said, I have it working now by renaming the file. Harly ideal (as needs a lot of housekeeping on the server to make sure those older versions are not kept and wasting disk space), but at least it works

Answer (score 1):

One of my Nginx configurations has this, which would probably point you in the right direction. Using "if" [isn't always ideal](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), but it seems to work fine for me.

```
set $skip_cache 0;
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}
if ($query_string != "") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}

if ($skip_cache = 1) {
  set $cacheControl "private, max-age=0, s-maxage=0, no-cache, no-store";
}
if ($skip_cache = 0) {
  set $cacheControl "public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400";
}

location /whatever/ {
  add_header Cache-Control $cacheControl;
}
```

Comment: thanks - that still doesn't seem to do it. Very odd :/ If I rotate the image, it doesn't update - yet if I copy the URL and open in a new tab, it shows the "old" version. Press Ctrl+F5 a few times, and it finally loads the new one :/

Comment: I wonder if this is because of how the browser caching behaves. As an experiment you could request an image, change the image on the Nginx server then restart it, then request it with a parameter. Check the Nginx log and see what code it sends, or if the request even makes it to Nginx.

Comment: I'm not too sure. The weird thing is that it works just fine on our Apache server, but we are moving over to nginx now as it's faster for most things (apart from Perl, as it would happen - so we have to use a reverse proxy for that part)

Answer (score 0):

OK, well this isn't an answer to my problem - but it has fixed the issue I had. Basically, I'm now just renaming the image, and then re-thumbing it to a different size. It's far from ideal (as I could have preferred to keep the original name), but it has already wasted too much of my time. I don't understand why nginx and Apache treat it differently, but it seems they do.